# PHP + SQLite duplicate inserts

Tags: php, sqlite, raspberry-pi

Every insert I do happens twice.
I thought the page might be getting hit twice so I also added a counter file that would increment on each load.  The page is only getting hit once, yet each insert is inserted twice.

```
<?
$x = intval(file_get_contents("./count.x"));
header("Content-type: text/plain");
$db = new SQLite3("/var/www/images/cache.db");

$statement = $db->prepare('insert into `imgCache` (name,type,data) values("test7","bmp","argh);');
$result = $statement->execute();


while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
print_r($row);
}


$x++;
file_put_contents("./count.x",$x);

?>
```

Prior to running this script there is no entry for "test7" in the database, and the contents of count.x is "0".

When I run this script, the following happens

1. count.x contains the text "1"
2. there are TWO entries for test7 in the database now.

Comment: Reading rows from an `INSERT` query doesn't make sense; `INSERT`s do not return anything. Also, using `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM imgCache` is much better than storing the count in a separate file.

Comment: The count was a debugging tool to quickly check if the script was getting called twice by the browser, not a fixture to remain in this permanantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP executes queries twice: one time to check whether any rows are returned, and a second time to actually return the rows.

An INSERT statement is not a query, and does not return rows.
Remove the `fetchArray` call.

Comment: I was using this on a machine I didn't have access to CLI to do initialize a database.  That makes sense then.  There were selects sometimes, but yeah, looks like I'll have to include logic or use separate files then.  Thanks.

Comment: Had the exact same issue. Wanted to return the row that was added but fetchArray wasn't doing that (i didnt test) nonetheless was causing duplicate entries.

Comment: Very valuable information. I was struggling with this problem. Thanks a lot.